# How can I separate my variables to another class?

Tags: vb.net

I found out that keeping a lot of variables, together with subs, functions, and other blocks of code in one class can be confusing to work with, so I want to separate my variables in another class.

This is what I'm thinking of:

```vb
Public Class Variables
    ' variables
    ' example: Dim Var1 As Integer
End Class

Public Class Form1
    ' the rest of the code
End Class
```

I want the variables inside to be just like global variables; it can be used by all other subs and functions within `Form1`, as if they *were* variables of `Form1`. How can I do that easily? Thanks, I hope you understood the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a [Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/module-statement) :

> A Module statement defines a reference type available throughout its namespace

All the fields declared as public or friend will be visible from the other classes in yout project.
For example:

```
Module Utility

    'A variable
    Public MyLink As String = "https://stackoverflow.com"

    'A function
    Public Function Sum(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
        Return a + b
    End Function

End Module
```

From another class, you can simply call all the the module methods/variables. For example:

```
Public Class Test

    Public Sub TestFunction()
        Dim result As Integer = Sum(1, 2)
        MessageBox.Show(MyLink)
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

If you don't want to use a module, but a class, you must declare the desired variables/functions as [Shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared). For example:

```
Public Class Utility

    Public Shared MyLink = "https://stackoverflow.com"

    Public Shared Function Sum(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
        Return a + b
    End Function

End Class
```

In this case, you probably must explicit the name of the class with shared fields:

```
Public Class Test

    Public Sub TestFunction()
        Dim result As Integer = Utility.Sum(1, 2)
        MessageBox.Show(Utility.MyLink)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: If I don't have preference for a module or a class, which of the two is better at doing this?

Comment: @UnoVillegas I suggest a *Module*... Conceptually, is a container of functions and variables useful to other classes, which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for using more than one Class, i.e. Form1, is to do work that's not always done in the Form1 functions and methods (Sub), or to do work that's broken up into different tasks.  For example, if you were developing a online banking package, you would do all the graphics (charts generation, and output) in a class for graphics, and do other separate analyses in other classes.

There are several ways to share variables over classes.  But when you advance to using threads, which can process the analysis of multiple classes simulateneously, you can run into "race conditions" for any shared variables.  So if e.g. a graphics class was generating graphs, and a variable "Balance" was 10000 for the checking account balance, and you were also processing data inside a class for the same customer's retirement account, if Balance was 40000, then Balance inside the graphics class could also be 40000, when it's supposed to be 10000.

Even if you're not running multiple classes simultaneously via threading, you can still get issues if Balance was 40000 after using the retirement class, and then you used the checking account class ( and somewhere didn't reset Balance to 10000).

If a variable like Balance can take on different values in different classes during threaded processing of multiple classes simultaneously, I typically will rename Balance to become chkBalance and retBalance for the checking and retirement classes.

You can then set

```
Public Class Checking
    Private chkBalance as Double 
    Sub New(ByVal chkBalance as Double) 'this is called the constructor for this class
       Call UseBalance(chkBalance)
    End Sub
    Sub UseBalance(ByVAl retBalance as Double)
     ... do work
    End Sub
       '...use chkBalance here
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Retirement
    Private retBalance as Double 
    Sub New(ByVal retBalance as Double) 'this is called the constructor for this class
       Call UseBalance(retBalance)
    End Sub
    Sub UseBalance(ByVal retBalance as Double)
       '...use retBalance here
    End Sub
End Class
```

If Balance is only going to be used, and won't change in the classes, you can send Balance from Form1 **by value** to these classes as follows:

```
Dim chk as New Checking(Balance)

Dim ret as New Retirement(Balance)
```

and Balance will become a different variable in each of the classes, without having a race condition.

However, if Balance can change inside methods in the classes, then you have to send it **by reference**:

```
Public Class Checking
    Private chkBalance as Double 
    Sub New(ByRef chkBalance as Double) 
       Call UpdateBalance(chkBalance)
    End Sub
    Sub UpdateBalance(ByRef chkBalance as Double)
     ... update chkBalance here
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Retirement
    Private retBalance as Double 
    Sub New(ByRef retBalance as Double) 
       Call UpdateBalance(retBalance)
    End Sub
    Sub UpdateBalance(ByRef retBalance as Double)
     ... update retBalance here
    End Sub
End Class
```